# Rails uninitialized constant Sprockets::Rails (Name Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, scaffold

I am trying to generate a controller with a rails app. However, the command prompt will not let me create the controller scaffold. It instead displays this error involving bootstrap-sass:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.6/lib/bootstrap-sass/engine.rb:11:in `block in <class:Engine>': uninitialized constant Sprockets::Rails (NameError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from C:/Sites/rails projects/Vumos/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

This is the gem file for the application:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'bootstrap-sass'

gem 'devise'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read     more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger      console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please show your Gemfile

Comment: I have the gemfile posted now.

Comment: Possibly a gem version incompatibility. Which versions of sprockets and sprockets-rails are installed? Perhaps show us `bundle show`.